How to specify a value that allows a loop to break
I am trying to do a loop that has to print x and y values until the remainder of the operation is 25 and the loop stops.
However, my first iteration of the code gets Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'x' before initialization. Therefore, I decided to change it and use for, but it does not matter if I use z < 25 or z <= 25, the loop won't stop.
//first iteration
let x=20;
let y=15;
let z=0;
while(z<=25){
    let x=x+25;
    let y=y+15;
    let z=x%y;
    console.log(x,y);
}

//second iteration
for( let z=0;z<25; x++,y++) {
    let z=x%y;
    console.log(x,y);
}


The problem is in your first solution you initialize the variables x and y again. Which is not necessary. I made some adjustments regarding adding the values to x and y.
Here is the updated code:


let x = 20;
let y = 15;
let z = 0;
while (z !== 25) {
  x += 25;
  y += 15;
  z = x % y;
  console.log(z); //Outputs 15 and 25
}



Glad to help! and enjoy your coding journey!

Your answer could be improved by putting the code in a runnable snippet.  I've done it for you in this case.

Just a simple comparison statement should work:

use while(z != 25){ }
as a good practice, evaluate the value of z ONCE before the while loop



var x=20;
var y=15;
var z=0;


z=x%y;

while(z != 25){
  x=x+25;
  y=y+15;
  z=x%y;
}

document.writeln('x='+ x + " and y=" + y);



The result will be x=70 and y=45
